# How to prevent multiples request by script in azure?

Tags: azure, request, azure-security

I have a backend .Net core hosted in azure, is possible to limit the requests per second per user? For example, if some user are logged in, he can create a script in javascript or maybe with postman and make a lot of requests per second with his token, is there any way to limit this? Because if he can do that, he will put very slow my backend.

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: This can be prevented by using API Management with Rate Policy: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-sample-flexible-throttling or with DDOS protection: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/ddos-protection/ddos-protection-overview

Comment: I recommend API Management as Markus mentioned. But if you want to roll your own, here's a good pattern with Redis: https://redis.com/redis-best-practices/basic-rate-limiting/